# Rename the rest of items as others Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe has 10 million rows, how to effectively group and rename the items other than "AA BB CC DD EE FF" to "others"?

original data

```
    name
0   AA
1   BB
2   CC
4   DD
5   EE
6   FF
7   htruj
9   uyd3
10  dr6y5
11  gery5
12  pihd
```

expect output

```
    name    new_name
0   AA       AA
1   BB       BB
2   CC       CC
4   DD       DD
5   EE       EE
6   FF       FF
7   htruj   others
9   uyd3    others
10  dr6y5   others
11  gery5   others
12  pihd    others
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `np.where` with `isin`

```
df['New']=np.where(df.name.isin(['AA','BB','CC','DD','EE','FF']),df.name,'other')
df
     name    New
0      AA     AA
1      BB     BB
2      CC     CC
4      DD     DD
5      EE     EE
6      FF     FF
7   htruj  other
9    uyd3  other
10  dr6y5  other
11  gery5  other
12   pihd  other
```